# How to resolve "undefined reference" error while statically linking cppunit?

Tags: c++, static-linking, cppunit

I am not sure why this question is marked as a duplicate of [Why does the order in which libraries are linked sometimes cause errors in GCC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45135/why-does-the-order-in-which-libraries-are-linked-sometimes-cause-errors-in-gcc). That question and this question are two totally different questions.

I have installed `libcppunit-dev` with `apt-get` on my Debian system.

```
$ dpkg -l libcppunit-dev
Desired=Unknown/Install/Remove/Purge/Hold
| Status=Not/Inst/Conf-files/Unpacked/halF-conf/Half-inst/trig-aWait/Trig-pend
|/ Err?=(none)/Reinst-required (Status,Err: uppercase=bad)
||/ Name                       Version            Architecture       Description
+++-==========================-==================-==================-==========================================================
ii  libcppunit-dev             1.13.2-2.1         amd64              Unit Testing Library for C++

$ dpkg -L libcppunit-dev | grep "libcppunit\."
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcppunit.a
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcppunit.so
```

I have written a simple test. Since my concern right now is only linking cppunit, I don't have a test runner yet. Ignore the lack of test runner for now. Here is my `test.cpp`:

```
#include <cppunit/extensions/HelperMacros.h>
#include <iostream>

class FooTest : public CppUnit::TestFixture
{
protected:
    void testFoo()
    {
        CPPUNIT_ASSERT_EQUAL(1 + 1, 2);
    }

private:
    CPPUNIT_TEST_SUITE(FooTest);
    CPPUNIT_TEST(testFoo);
    CPPUNIT_TEST_SUITE_END();
};

CPPUNIT_TEST_SUITE_REGISTRATION(FooTest);

int main()
{
    std::cout << "hello\n";
    return 0;
}
```

Dynamic linking works fine:

```
$ g++ -lcppunit test.cpp && ./a.out
hello
```

Static linking fails:

```
$ g++ -l:libcppunit.a test.cpp
/tmp/ccwMWIsX.o: In function `CppUnit::AdditionalMessage::~AdditionalMessage()':
test.cpp:(.text._ZN7CppUnit17AdditionalMessageD2Ev[_ZN7CppUnit17AdditionalMessageD5Ev]+0x14): undefined reference to `CppUnit::Message::~Message()'
/tmp/ccwMWIsX.o: In function `FooTest::testFoo()':
test.cpp:(.text._ZN7FooTest7testFooEv[_ZN7FooTest7testFooEv]+0x70): undefined reference to `CppUnit::SourceLine::SourceLine(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, int)'
test.cpp:(.text._ZN7FooTest7testFooEv[_ZN7FooTest7testFooEv]+0xa5): undefined reference to `CppUnit::SourceLine::~SourceLine()'
test.cpp:(.text._ZN7FooTest7testFooEv[_ZN7FooTest7testFooEv]+0xe9): undefined reference to `CppUnit::SourceLine::~SourceLine()'
/tmp/ccwMWIsX.o: In function `FooTest::getTestNamer__()':
test.cpp:(.text._ZN7FooTest14getTestNamer__Ev[_ZN7FooTest14getTestNamer__Ev]+0x41): undefined reference to `CppUnit::TestNamer::TestNamer(std::type_info const&)'
```

What can I do to ensure that static linking with cppunit succeeds?

Comment: Is the colon after -legally not the problem?

Comment: Show your test.cpp please.

Comment: @Ext3h Added test.cpp in the question. Sorry, forgot to include it when I posted the question initially.

Comment: @LoneLearner reopened :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to link your program and the library in another order

```
g++ test.cpp -l:libcppunit.a
```

Or

```
g++ test.cpp /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcppunit.a
```

Or

```
g++ test.cpp -static -lcppunit -Wl,-Bdynamic
```

The last `-Wl,-Bdynamic` is required to avoid static linkage of system libraries like libc++ or glibc.

Comment: `g++ test.cpp -l:libcppunit.a` led to this error: `/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/6/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libcppunit.a(AdditionalMessage.o): relocation R_X86_64_32 against symbol `__gxx_personality_v0@@CXXABI_1.3' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC`

Comment: The `g++ test.cpp -static -lcppunit -dynamic` worked but generated warnings like `cc1plus: warning: unrecognized gcc debugging option: y`, `cc1plus: warning: unrecognized gcc debugging option: n`, etc.

Comment: `g++ test.cpp -l:libcppunit.a -fPIC` also led to this error: `/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/6/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libcppunit.a(AdditionalMessage.o): relocation R_X86_64_32 against symbol `__gxx_personality_v0@@CXXABI_1.3' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC`.

Comment: I am using g++ 6.3.0.

Comment: `g++ test.cpp /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcppunit.a` leads to:
`/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcppunit.a(AdditionalMessage.o): relocation R_X86_64_32 against symbol `__gxx_personality_v0@@CXXABI_1.3' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC`

Comment: `g++ test.cpp -static -lcppunit -Wl,-Bdynamic && ./a.out` leads to this error: `bash: ./a.out: No such file or directory`.

Comment: Do you know why then `g++ test.cpp -static -lcppunit` works fine?

Comment: It works fine because of libc++ is linked statically too. But libcppunit.a does not want to link with dynamic libc++.